# java script Foreach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5000;) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
    }, i);
    i += 500;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

**How to increase " i " every 5ms and print it in #demo every time it changes**

I am trying to make a look that increases the value of ( **i** ) once every 5ms, and prints it out in   **#** demo.

Right now, the value **5000** immediately prints out as soon as I run the script for some reason, as opposed to increasing by 500 every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code isn't clear

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it now. Any better?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `myFunction` to:

```
var i = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var timerId = setInterval(function(){ 
        if(i >= 5000)
        {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
        i +=500;
    }, 5);
}
```

Comment: It is still not printing out each time i increases :(

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
var i=0;

function looper(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
console.log(i+" data");
i=i+500;
if(i<5000)
looper();
}, i);
}

looper();
```

Comment: How to I stop the loop? for the foreach I can say i >= 5000

Comment: @mark `if(i < 5000) { looper(); }`, inside `setTimeout`. This answer isn't correct though. The timeout is `i`, should be 5ms. The increment is `5`, should be `500`. And no condition to stop loop as said.

Comment: @Arg0n thanks, i've updated it. & yes mark put up any condition you want in the place where the method calls itself, according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
   var i = 0;
   var max = 5000;
   var step = 500;
   var intervalMs = 5;

   var interval = setInterval(function() {
     // clear interval if one step before max value
     if (i >= max-step) {
       clearInterval(interval);  
     }

     // increment i by step
     i+=step;

     // set inner html of div
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
   }, intervalMs)
}
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/IfkGOpjUnf4sKpN4iCZ4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with the closure not saving a reference to your timeout. Subsequent arguments after the second are passed into the callback function as arguments.

Here we are passing `i` as the third argument

```
setTimeout(fn, delay, i)
```

Then in the callaback we have access to the `i`, we are reassigning it to `x` within the scope of the callback.

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5000; i = i + 500) {
    setTimeout(function(x) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }, i, i);
  }
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

```js
function myFunction(max, ii = 0) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ii
  if (ii < max) {
    setTimeout(myFunction, 500, max, ii + 500)
  }
}
myFunction(5000)
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just found out that this isn't actually printing out the i value as it increases by 500ms. Its just printing the value of x which is an independent timer of i

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to look similar to what you have, you can use an IIFE:

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5000;i += 500) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = index;
        }, index);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I needed to to increase similar every 500ms. I've got the answer now :) thanks again

Comment: @mark Then you should probably change `How to increase " i " every 5ms` to `How to increase " i " every 500ms` in your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Acctually, it's in two places in your question. `... the value of ( i ) once every 5ms ...` also.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
        var i = 0;
        var setClock = function() {
            if (i < 5000) {
                local = i;
                i += 500;

            setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = local; setTimeout(setClock, 500);},
                500);
            }
        }
        setClock();
    }
```

**

1. you should wrap scripts in  tags
2. the javascript Closures. You should know that because of the Closures, second parameters for all setTimeout() are 5000, which is the i's final value. You can avoid the Closure by the codes I showed or erase the impact of Closure by below codes:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
        var local;
        for (i = 0; i < 5000; i+= 500) {
            local = i;
            setTimeout((function(interval){
                return function() {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = interval;} ;
            })(local), (function(interval){return interval})(local));
        }
}
```